# Combining the blessing of Benjamin with the death of Jacob

Tags: safrus, shevatim-12-tribes, vayechi

When I was reading the [blessing of Jacob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaychi#Fourth_reading_%E2%80%94_Genesis_49:1%E2%80%9318) ([Bereishit 49](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm)), it caught my attention that the blessing of Benjamin and the summary is combined with the death and the funeral of Jacob. Based on [Sifra](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Vayikra_Dibbura_d%27Nedavah%2C_Chapter_1.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Rashi ([Vayikra 1:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9902/showrashi/true#v1)) and Maharshal ([שו"ת ל"ז](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49542&st=&pgnum=50) – כי רבותינו  הקדמונים וכו'‏) suggest that the division into [parashot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah) more or [less](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8242/showrashi/true#v28) follows the topics discussed in the text. Yet, this particular blessing is organised in the following way:

- Reuven (after two introductory verses) – open paragraph
- Shimon and Levi – open paragraph, combined due to their [conspiracy](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8244/showrashi/true#v5)
- Yehudah, Zevulun – each separated by an open paragraph
- Yissakhar, Dan, Gad, Asher, Naftali – each separated by a closed paragraph, end of *aliyah* after Dan
- Joseph – open paragraph, end of *aliyah*
- Benjamin (followed by a summarising verse) – 
  **not separated from the rest of the paragraph discussing another topic**

Indeed, it happens that in similar lists the last item goes with the summary (Bemidbar [26:48](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0426.htm#48)–51 or [29:35](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0429.htm#35)–30:1, Devarim [33:24](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm#24)–29),* but I didn't find any other instances when it is added to another paragraph discussing a totally different topic. Are there any explanations why Benjamin is added to the subsequent paragraph? Was he considered anything different from the rest of his brothers? Can it be a parallel with the death of his mother?

<sup>* In contrast with other cases where the last item and the summary are separated: Bemidbar [1:42](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0401.htm#42)–43 and 44–47, [7:78](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0407.htm#78)–83 and 84–89,</sup>

Comment: I wonder whether there might be some connection with the fact that his stone on the Choshen was multicolored, incorporating the colors of all of the other Shevatim's stones (and flags). So maybe, in the same vein, his berachah is placed in the same paragraph that mentions the twelve of them.

Comment: In English paragraph breaks can also mark topical divisions and list divisions (commonly, different speakers). Imagine: Topic topic topic topic topic Speaker1 Speaker2 topic. No one would be bothered by the last topic sentence being too short to be a paragraph on its own. Because the list breaks don't interrupt the topic.

Comment: @Meir What about Reuvein also being in such a paragraph?

Comment: @DoubleAA His paragraph doesn't actually mention the number 12. But you're right, there's probably more to consider here.

Comment: No, 88 is the last central verse and 89 is the closer. It is attached as expected. In parallel to verse 1. You are focusing only on the end but the pattern is expected in the beginnings as well.

Comment: "discussing a totally different topic" Why is Yaakov's deathbed speech and his death and burial a totally different topic? Avraham's death and burial isn't in it's own section (Gen 25). Nor Yitzchak (Gen 35). Nor David (Kings 1:2). Are there any counterexamples?? (Yehoshua has a break there but that also represents a change in authorship. Same arguably mutatis mutandis for Moshe.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I suppose Keturah is there to show the contrast regarding Yitzchak in his will, so it seems connected to me. Yitzchak's death is a better example, but it's just two verses. In the case of David (Kings I 2:1-12) the last will and the death is combined, which doesn't contradict what I'm saying (putting a break before M1 49:29).

Comment: @Kazibácsi (Yaakov's final blessings and his final instructions seem way more related than Keturah.) Nothing can contradict it because no one can prove it has to be some way. It's just abundantly clear from all these examples that the current way isn't weird. It's well within the normal bounds of what gets grouped into a parsha. Not "a totally different topic".

Answer (score 3):

Though this is a very striking example, there are a number of places in the Torah where the breaks, psucha and stumah, divide the middle parts of a list and not the beginning and/or the end. I don't have a complete list of examples, but might as well start with the punishments of the nachash, Chava, and Adam in [Bereishis 3:14-19](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). There are more, though not every one is at both at the beginning and the end of the list.
In other words, the answer to your question is that the blessing of Binyamin is not actually combined with the following section. It is just not separated from it. The rest of the brothers' blessings are not separated from it either - they are separated from one another.

Comment: Very nice example

Comment: Also later Bereishis 5:32-6:1

Comment: Yeah, there're lots once you start looking for them. My favorite is the list of tumah in Parshas Shemini; there's a section on "tumah" of things you can't eat, no breaks. In the middle of it is a sub-section on tumos of touching, which has two stumos in the middle. Afterward it switches back into tumah of eating with no break.

Comment: I suppose you make a really interesting claim. Have you by any chance found a source which supports your point of view?

Comment: @Kazibácsi Isn't this exactly what I've been arguing for in the comments on the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA I second that; I was just chiming in to support DoubleAA.

Comment: @Kazibácsi, I don't have a proper source; I would love to find one. I do have a fair number of examples. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bAf_dC1guctCnVBTursrclO2IdnyVS2G/view?usp=sharing around p. 165.

Comment: @Double Partially yes, but I suppose the new thing is that different topics are not necessarily divided into different paragraphs and we shouldn't think too much about the divisions. If an authority supports this claim, I'm happy to accept the answer. (Sifra et al. were arguing the other way around: if there's a break a new topic is discussed.)

Comment: Yipes - I certainly didn't mean to say that "we shouldn't think too much about the divisions". More accurate to say that the common assumption people make about the divisions - that everything between two divisions is considered to be grouped _together_ - is not always right. See my writeup above for my best attempt at putting some pieces together.

Comment: @Michoel "everything between two divisions is considered to be grouped together is not always right" I'd say it differently: everything separated by parsha breaks is not equally separated. Adam's curse is separate from Chava's in some regard, but all the curses are still connected to the text before and after, despite the two breaks.

Comment: Yeah. I guess the normal assumption is that since there are only two types of break, פתוחה and סתומה, we are dealing with a tree decomposition with at most two levels (we assume that פתוחה is a bigger break, Teshuvas Maharshal 37). A table of contents, so to speak. It seems that isn't true. Some judgment is required to decide what level you're currently on. In the case of the curses, you're supposed to know that you're already in the "curses" sub-section, which is part of the larger section. Or some such.